# How to create an index of a text with all words of the text

Tags: indexing

How I do create an index of a text with all words of the text. Words in the index must have the reference of the section, the page and the line where is the word.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Ramon Masià. Buon lavoro!

Comment: This kind of index is usually called a concordance. Related: [How to generate an automatic index (concordance) in a large file?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/398627)

Comment: Reference to line numbers is hard, since TeX has no real concept of a line. See [How to automatically reference line numbers of a quote?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/515094) for one approach.